# Pixel by pixel image hashing methods

Tags: image, hash, duplicates, jpeg

I'm trying to remove damaged jpeg duplicates of some 27k photos. Unfortunately most of these are actually damaged duplicates showing half or less of the original image before cutting out to mess/grey.

Is there any intelligent algorithm to hash a picture that instead of hashing a reduced size version of the full image (as in aHash, pHash and dHash) does it pixel by pixel (starting top left and reading LTR)?

The thing is most algorithms just reduce the image size and then create an hash in order to compare the pictures. As these damaged files really lack most of the data it's impossible to compare the first "few lines or few pixels of an image". The only software coming close to this is AllDup, but it only does a comparison bit-by-bit and not checking the actual image data.

Would that even be possible?

Thanks in advance.